# Scala - How to initialize a map of maps in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Trying to learn Scala. I want to initialize a Map of Maps.
My Java code would look something like this:

**(* Using computeIfAbsent)**

```
 private static void initMap() {
    mapAdd(new App("ID_A", "Site1", "app_AAA", "A_A_A_A"));
    mapAdd(new App("ID_B", "Site1", "app_BBB", "B_B_B_B"));
    mapAdd(new App("ID_C", "Site2", "app_CCC", "C_C_C_C"));
    mapAdd(new App("ID_D", "Site2", "app_DDD", "D_D_D_D"));
}

private static void mapAdd(App app) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(app.siteId, x -> new HashMap<>()).put(app.name, app);
}
```

My Scala looks like this

```
val app1 = new AppKey("ID_A", "Site1", "app_AAA", "A_A_A_A")
val app2 = new AppKey("ID_B", "Site1", "app_BBB", "B_B_B_B")
val app3 = new AppKey("ID_C", "Site2", "app_CCC", "C_C_C_C")
val app4 = new AppKey("ID_D", "Site2", "app_DDD", "D_D_D_D")

val nameToAppKey1 = mutable.Map[String, AppKey](app1.name -> app1)
nameToAppKey1 += (app2.name -> app2)

val nameToAppKey2 = mutable.Map[String, AppKey](app3.name -> app3)
nameToAppKey2 += (app4.name -> app4)

map += ("Site1" -> nameToAppKey1)
map += ("Site2" -> nameToAppKey2)
```

It looks like it's was written by a Java refugee.
What is the best practice to initialize a Map of Maps in Scala?

Comment: How about using filter for finding siteId and then creating a map?

Answer (score 1):

Initialising the data...

```
//whatever your case class is
case class AppKey(id: String, site: String, appName: String, name: String)

val app1 = AppKey("ID_A", "Site1", "app_AAA", "A_A_A_A")
val app2 = AppKey("ID_B", "Site1", "app_BBB", "B_B_B_B")
val app3 = AppKey("ID_C", "Site2", "app_CCC", "C_C_C_C")
val app4 = AppKey("ID_D", "Site2", "app_DDD", "D_D_D_D")

val apps = Seq(app1, app2, app3, app4)
```

If you are trying to group the apps by Site, you can specify what you need exactly, like this:

```
Map (
  "Site2" -> apps.filter(appKey => appKey.site == "Site2"),
  "Site1" -> apps.filter(appKey => appKey.site == "Site1")
)
```

or do it in a one-liner:

```
apps.groupBy(_.site)
```

Both of these methods give the following output (formatted for readability):

```
Map(
  Site2 -> List(AppKey(ID_C,Site2,app_CCC,C_C_C_C),AppKey(ID_D,Site2,app_DDD,D_D_D_D)),
  Site1 -> List(AppKey(ID_A,Site1,app_AAA,A_A_A_A),AppKey(ID_B,Site1,app_BBB,B_B_B_B))
)
```

If you want to further group by something like ID, you can do something like this:

```
apps.groupBy(_.site).mapValues(_.groupBy(_.id))
```

which gives the following output:

```
Map(
  Site2 -> 
    Map(
      ID_D -> List(AppKey(ID_D,Site2,app_DDD,D_D_D_D)),
      ID_C -> List(AppKey(ID_C,Site2,app_CCC,C_C_C_C))
    ),
  Site1 ->
    Map(
      ID_A -> List(AppKey(ID_A,Site1,app_AAA,A_A_A_A)),
      ID_B -> List(AppKey(ID_B,Site1,app_BBB,B_B_B_B))
    )
)
```

For more complex examples, you can just keep adding `.mapValues(_.groupBy(_.{...}))`, or specifying exactly what you want to group by similar to the first example. Note that in Scala, you don't really need to specify the `new` keyword - in most scenarios, it is implied anyway (same as with semicolons).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might help

```
case class AppKey(id: String, name: String, name1: String, name2: String) //whatever your case class is
val app1 = new AppKey("ID_A", "Site1", "app_AAA", "A_A_A_A")
val app2 = new AppKey("ID_B", "Site1", "app_BBB", "B_B_B_B")
val app3 = new AppKey("ID_C", "Site2", "app_CCC", "C_C_C_C")
val app4 = new AppKey("ID_D", "Site2", "app_DDD", "D_D_D_D")

List(app1, app2, app3, app4).groupBy(_.id).map {
  case (id, lst) => (id, lst.find(_.id == id))
}
```

And replace `find` with `filter` to get list of values (in Map)

Result will be:

with `find`

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Option[AppKey]] = Map(ID_D -> Some(AppKey(ID_D,Site2,app_DDD,D_D_D_D)), ID_A -> Some(AppKey(ID_A,Site1,app_AAA,A_A_A_A)), ID_C -> Some(AppKey(ID_C,Site2,app_CCC,C_C_C_C)), ID_B -> Some(AppKey(ID_B,Site1,app_BBB,B_B_B_B)))
```

and with `filter`

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[AppKey]] = Map(Site2 -> List(AppKey(ID_C,Site2,app_CCC,C_C_C_C), AppKey(ID_D,Site2,app_DDD,D_D_D_D)), Site1 -> List(AppKey(ID_A,Site1,app_AAA,A_A_A_A), AppKey(ID_B,Site1,app_BBB,B_B_B_B)))
```